# SQL Select In Random Order BUT Do Not Select Duplicate From A Specifc Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

Ok so I have my database that has multiple ads...BUT I have multiple ads from the same site that have been added....here is an example.

[image]

As you can see...the database has two links that are different...but they lead to the same site.  My goal is to have it RANDOMLY select one of them and display it but not the other WHILE ALSO selecting all of the others and displaying those as well.  Here is the coding I have at the moment for it:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `ads`';
        $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            extract($row);
            echo '
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card mb-30"><a class="card-img-tiles" href="'.$link.'">
                    <div class="inner">
                      <div class="main-img"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.$alt_title.'"></div>
                    </div></a>
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h4 class="card-title">'.$name.'</h4>
                    '.$about.'
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" href="'.$link.'">Check It Out</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ';
            }
?>
```

I want it to display the circled ones randomly selected but not both for each set.

[image]

Comment: You can use this link for more reference.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24327/how-to-select-distinct-for-one-column-and-any-in-another-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 8.0 of MySQL (or MariaDB 10.2), you can select one random record in each group of records having the same `mainsite` using `ROW_NUMBER()`, and then sort randomly in the outer query with `ORDER BY RAND()`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mainsite ORDER BY RAND()) rn
    FROM ads t
) x WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
```

---

With earlier versions of MySQL / MariaDB, this gets tedier. One solution is to use a pair of variables to track groups and assign row numbers :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.*,
        CASE
            WHEN @mainsite != mainsite THEN @rn := 1
            ELSE @rn := @rn + 1
        END rn,
        @mainsite := mainsite
        FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM ads ORDER  BY RAND()) a
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @mainsite := NULL) r
        ORDER  BY a.mainsite
    ) s
WHERE  rn <= 1
ORDER  BY RAND()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `OVER(PARTITION BY mainsite ORDER BY RAND())`?

Comment: Still trying to understand this??? I understand that "mytable" would be replaced with "ads" but I don't understand if I have to replace anything else...

Comment: @PaulSpiegel : yes absolutely. I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: This is what I have right now `SELECT * FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mainsite ORDER BY RAND()) rn FROM ads t) x WHERE rn = 1`

Comment: @RobertAmes : the subquery assigns a number to each record within the group of records that have the same `mainsite`. You can run it independently to see the results : `SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mainsite ORDER BY RAND()) rn FROM ads t`

Comment: When there are several records having the same `mainsite`, one of them  (randomly) will get row number 1, and others will be numbered 2, 3, ... When a there is no duplicate record, the unique record in the group will get number 1.

Comment: I run this but get nothing....I have no fields show up at all.... `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY Mainsite ORDER BY RAND()) rn FROM ads t LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using ? You need 8.0 to use analytics functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: 10.0.31-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

Comment: Analytic functions come in version 10.2... OK so we would need to use another solution. Let me check again. One question : in the output, do you need all columns from `ads` for the selected records, or just the `mainsite` is enough ?

Comment: I need all the columns in order to display the ad through PHP.

Comment: @RobertAmes : I updated my answer with a solution without using analytic functions. It should work on your version of MariaDB.

Comment: @GMB : Thank you so much for all of your help...I really appreciate everything you have done to help me out :)  This works perfectly.  I've always had trouble with more extensive stuff like this but basic queries I seem to have down.